# Change gridview column color due to expiration date

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to change the an expiration date column on a gridview. I want to change color when I am past the current date or within 15 days of current date change color to red and if 15 to 30 days from current data date set color to yellow. When I try to implement the rowdatabound while trying to set datetime variable I am missing rows from gridview and colors are not shown.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowSorting="True" OnDataBound="GridView1_DataBound" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound1">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="MLSId" HeaderText="MLSId" SortExpression="MLSId" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Agent_FName" HeaderText="First Name" SortExpression="Agent_FName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Agent_LName" HeaderText="Last Name" SortExpression="Agent_LName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="License_Num" HeaderText="License #" SortExpression="License_Num" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="License Exp" SortExpression="License_Exp">
             <EditItemTemplate>
                 <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("License_Exp") %>'></asp:TextBox>
             </EditItemTemplate>
             <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("License_Exp", "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}") %>'></asp:Label>
             </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
   </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Code Behind,

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound1(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= GridView1.Rows.Count-1; i++)
    {
        DateTime lblDate = Convert.ToDateTime(GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("Label1"));

        if (lblDate <= DateTime.Now.AddDays(15))
        {
            GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].BackColor = Color.Red;
        }
        else if (lblDate >= DateTime.Now.AddDays(16) && lblDate <= DateTime.Now.AddDays(30))
        {
            GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].BackColor = Color.Yellow;
        }
        else
        {
            GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].BackColor = Color.Blue;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need `for` block inside `GridView1_RowDataBound1`, here's what you should do instead:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound1(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        string dateText = ((Label)e.Row.FindControl("Label1")).Text;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dateText))
        {
            DateTime dateValue = DateTime.ParseExact(dateText, "MM/dd/yyyy", null);

            if (dateValue <= DateTime.Now.AddDays(15))
            {
                e.Row.Cells[4].BackColor = Color.Red;
            }
            else if (dateValue >= DateTime.Now.AddDays(16) && dateValue <= DateTime.Now.AddDays(30))
            {
                e.Row.Cells[4].BackColor = Color.Yellow;
            }
            else
            {
                e.Row.Cells[4].BackColor = Color.Blue;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            e.Row.Cells[4].BackColor = Color.Blue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When I come to a null value for the date cell the gridview stops instead of defaulting to the blue and continuing the loop. If I could default to blue or leave blank/white and continue the condition for the rest of the possible values would be the goal. I was trying the for loop to continue past  the null values but that doesn't work.

Comment: See my edited answer, the back color will be blue if the date is null

Answer (score 1):

`RowDataBound` event is raised for each row and you can get the row using `e.Row`

You can change the code as below. make sure you have find the label and convert it to date time without any errors.

```
 protected void GridView1_RowDataBound1(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
  {
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        Label a = e.Row.FindControl("Label1") as Label;
        if (a != null)
        {
            DateTime lblDate;
            if(!DateTime.TryParse(a.Text, out lblDate)
            {
                // date time conversion not success 
                // you may have empty or invalid datetime 
                // do something in this case 
                return;
            }
            if (lblDate <= DateTime.Now.AddDays(15))
            {
                e.Row.Cells[4].BackColor = Color.Red;

            }
            else if (lblDate >= DateTime.Now.AddDays(16) && lblDate <= DateTime.Now.AddDays(30))
            {
                e.Row.Cells[4].BackColor = Color.Yellow;

            }
            else
            {
                e.Row.Cells[4].BackColor = Color.Blue;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works until it comes to a null value for the date. I tried to add an else but it still will not fill the gridview past the null label. only follows the logic until the null value.

Comment: what you want to do if you have empty value for Label1.Text?

Comment: I was trying to have anything not entered / null for that cell to be white.